# What should i specify in action attribute of form tag in this case?

Tags: java, html, servlets, model-view-controller, netbeans

i want to send the form data to Controller.java servlet 
which is in the directory
 Source Package/mvc/Contoller.java of Netbeans
// mvc is the package name

i've tried 
action="/Controller"
action="mvc/Controller"
action="/mvc/Controller
but these are not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just `action="Controller"` would be fine.

The mappings of the servlets is done in `web.xml` file which you can find in your project folder.

Comment: Don't just down-vote. Give the reason. It will help everyone.

Comment: i didn't down-vote and i don't have enough reputation to vote-up

Comment: Its not you @ArpitTomar, but someone did. Glad I could help :)